# Diagonalizable linear transformations...

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$ and that $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation such that $T^4=I$. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable, and that this does not necessarily hold when $V$ is taken over $\Bbb R$.

I haven't tried much on this since I do not know where to start really.

Comment: What can you say about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: Well, if they were distinct that'd be nice, but I don't know why they should be.

Comment: They won't be distinct in general. But which eigenvalues are possible at all? (That's for the $\mathbb{R}$ part, by the way, for the $\mathbb{C}$ part, look at the Jordan normal form.)

Comment: Are you aware of the theorem that an operator is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}$ iff its minimial polynomial splits over $\mathbb{F}$ into a product of distinct linear factors?

Comment: I was not aware of that theorem, that'll do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The polynomial $x^4-1$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb C$ and annihilates $T$ so $T$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.
- The rotation matrix by the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a counterexample.